# id value does not seem to be captured correctly in servlet

Tags: java, model-view-controller, jsp, servlets, jstl

If I arbitrarily assign an 'id' value in the implementing servlet it works; however, if I dont it correctly inherits the id value from the abstract class and skips over the 'if' statement to forward to the url provided in the 'then' statement.  What gives? Can tell what is wrong with the 'id' variable:

Abstract servlet snipet:

```
 protected Integer id = null;

 private void _doProcess(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
    try {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        writer = response.getWriter();
        final String idString = request.getParameter("id");
        if(StringUtil.isNotEmptyStringTrimmed(idString)){
            try {
                id = Integer.parseInt(idString.trim());
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                id = null;
            }
        }

        doProcess(request,response);

    } finally {
        id = null;
    }

    try {
        writer.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // no-op
    }
}
```

implementing servlet snipet:

```
 public void doProcess(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response)
        throws IOException, ServletException {

    // set page title
    final HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    session.setAttribute("pageTitle", "Training Project 5: Author");

    if (id == null){
        request.setAttribute("authorNamesList", printAuthorNames());
        request.getRequestDispatcher("authorList.jsp").include(request,response);
    }else{
        final Author author = BEAN_FACTORY.getMember(id);
        session.setAttribute("authorId",author.getId());
        session.setAttribute("name", author.getName());
        session.setAttribute("bio", author.getBio());
        session.setAttribute("picture",author.getPicture());
        session.setAttribute("bookTitles", printBookTitles(author.getId()));
        request.getRequestDispatcher("authorPage.jsp").include(request,response);
    }
}
```

The below jsp code works when the above servlet 'else' code is not in the conditional statement:

```
 <div id="right">
   <table class="display" summary="Author Information">         
     <tr>
         <td><span class="brown">Author Id: <c:out value="${authorId}"/></span></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
         <td><span class="brown">Name: <c:out value="${name}"/></span></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
         <td><span class="brown">Bio: <c:out value="${bio}"/></span></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
         <td>
             <p>
                 <span class="brown"><img src="<c:out value="${picture}"/>" alt= ""/></span>
             </p>
         </td>
     </tr>
```

Comment: What is the `id` variable? where is it defined? where is it receiving value?

Comment: Is id undefined? Is it initialized at all?

Comment: The id variable is defined in the abstract class that this servlet extends from:

Comment: final String idString = request.getParameter("id");
            if(StringUtil.isNotEmptyStringTrimmed(idString)){
                try {
                    id = Integer.parseInt(idString.trim());
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    id = null;
                }
            }

Comment: Please update the question to reflect the `id` variable.

Answer (score 3):

Unless `id` is a class field, you're not showing us all the code. It's also unclear what you mean by 'it doesn't work.' The expected content is empty? You get an exception?

Comment: I don't get an exception, it just doesn't populate to the session.  To check, I printed out all the session variables and nothing was there. However, if I change the value of 'id' and take the contents of the 'else' block out of the if/then statement it prints fine in my jsp page.

Comment: Looks like it might be an issue with the id . . . I just left the if/then statement intact and just entered:  id = 2 and it printed out fine.  Its weird though, without overwriting the exiting id value, the program flow knows to skip over the if statement and go to the else .jsp redirect.  Crazy.

Answer (score 1):

'Id' will always be null or undefined rather if its not initialized.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out what the issue was. . . sorry guys (and gals) I didn't give everyone enough info to solve the problem.  There is a authorList.jsp page that prints the list that everyone chooses from (see below).  The user chooses the author they want to see information about in the authorList.jsp page, then the author id parameter is forwarded back to the servlet which forwards the user to the authorPage.jsp which displays the individual author information.

Basically, I had used the exact .jsp name of the following jsp page (authorPage.jsp) as opposed to the servlet mapping designation on the web.xml (listAuthor).  I had:

```
    <table summary="Author List">
        <c:forEach items="${authorNamesList}" var="name">
            <tr>
               <td><span class="brown"><a href="authorPage.jsp?id=${name.key}">${name.value}</a></span></td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
```

Should have been:

```
    <table summary="Author List">
        <c:forEach items="${authorNamesList}" var="name">
            <tr>
               <td><span class="brown"><a href="listAuthor?id=${name.key}">${name.value}</a></span></td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </table>
```

Some times it's better to just leave and come back later to look at it fresh!  Happy Thanksgiving everybody:)